# Socket.io not working on some client networking

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a chat app using nodejs and socket.io running on port 49158 on a mutual server, so i can not use the standard port 80.

In some networks the client can log in using sockets but can't send any message.
Thanks in advance.

Client code :

```
var messagToSend = e.data.messageToSend;
      messagToSend.id = self.user.id;
      messagToSend.token = self.user.token;
      self._socket.emit('newmsg',messagToSend, function (err, data) {
        if (err == null) {
          self.toastr.success('Message was sent successefully');
          self.newMessageWindow.close();
        } else {
          self.toastr.error(`Bad emails : ${data} `);
          self.newMessageWindow.close();
        }
      });
```

Server code :

```
    socket.on('newmsg', function (data, callback) {

    if (data && data.id && data.titre && data.message && data.emails && typeof(data.notify_me) === "boolean" && data.token) {
        var user = null;
        var titre = data.titre;
        var message_content = data.message;
        var emails = data.emails;
        var notify_me = data.notify_me;
        var token = data.token;
        var id = data.id;
        var badusers = [];


        // verification si le  user est bon

        User.get(id, function (err, connected_user) {
            if (!err) {
                user = connected_user;
                if (user !== null) {
                    // verification du token
                    if ((jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh')) && (jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh')).email == user.email) {
                        // bon token
                        Sync(function () {
                            // on cree le message
                            try {
                                var message = Message.create.sync(null, {
                                    titre: titre,
                                    content: message_content,
                                    notify_me: notify_me
                                });
                                if (message !== null) {
                                    // message created  we can add the sender
                                    try {
                                        var sender = message.setSender.sync(null, user);
                                        if (sender !== null) {
                                            // on parcours les emails
                                            for (let i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
                                                let email_destinaire = emails[i];
                                                let destinataires = User.find.sync(null, {email: email_destinaire}, 1);

                                                if (destinataires.length > 0) {
                                                    let destinataire = destinataires[0];

                                                    // verification si le user est online ou pas
                                                    var k = 0;
                                                    var en_ligne = false;
                                                    while (en_ligne == false && k != online.length) {
                                                        if (online[k].email == destinataire.email) {
                                                            en_ligne = true;
                                                        } else {
                                                            k++;
                                                        }

                                                    }
                                                    if (en_ligne == true) {
                                                        // on fait un emit
                                                        io.sockets.connected[online[k].socket_id].emit('newmsg', {
                                                            id: message.id,
                                                            titre: message.titre,
                                                            content: message.content,
                                                            created_at: message.created_at,
                                                            notify_me: message.notify_me,
                                                            user: user
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                    // on enregistre dans les receivers
                                                    // on enregistre dans les receivers
                                                    message.addReceivers(destinataire, {vu: false}, function (err, dest) {
                                                        if (!err) {

                                                           /* if (enligne == true) {
                                                                // recuperation de la liste des favoris
                                                                user.getFavoris(function (err, favoris) {
                                                                    if (!err) {
                                                                        var z = 0;
                                                                        var trouve = false;
                                                                        while (trouve == false && z != favoris.length) {
                                                                            if (favoris[z].email == destinataire.email) {
                                                                                trouve = true;
                                                                            } else {
                                                                                z++;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                        if (trouve == false) {
                                                                            user.addFavoris(destinataire, function (err, favoris_added) {
                                                                                if (!err) {
                                                                                    var fav = {
                                                                                        id: favoris_added[0].id,
                                                                                        email: favoris_added[0].email,
                                                                                        pseudo: favoris_added[0].pseudo
                                                                                    };
                                                                                    socket.emit('newfavoris', fav);

                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        }

                                                                    } else {
                                                                        //
                                                                    }
                                                                })
                                                            }*/
                                                            bdd_tchat.query('select  *  FROM user_favoris WHERE user_id=? AND favoris_id=?', [user.id, destinataire.id], function (err, rows) {
                                                                if(!err){
                                                                    if(rows.length ==0){
                                                                        // insert the new
                                                                        let ob = {'user_id':user.id,'favoris_id':destinataire};
                                                                        bdd_tchat.query('insert into user_favoris SET ?',ob, function (err, rows){
                                                                               if(!err){
                                                                                   socket.emit('newfavoris',{
                                                                                       'id': destinataire.id,
                                                                                       'email': destinataire.email,
                                                                                       'pseudo': destinataire.pseudo
                                                                                   })
                                                                               }
                                                                        });
                                                                    }
                                                                }

                                                            });

                                                        } else {
                                                            // erreur  dans l'ajout du destinaire

                                                        }
                                                    });

                                                } else {
                                                    badusers.push(email_destinaire);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            if (badusers.length == 0) {
                                                callback(null, 200)
                                            } else {
                                                if (badusers.length == emails.length) {
                                                    try {
                                                        let result = message.remove.sync(null);
                                                        console.log("Message droped");
                                                        callback('badmails', badusers);
                                                    } catch (e) {
                                                        //console.log(err);
                                                    }

                                                } else {
                                                    callback('badmails', badusers)
                                                }
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            // impossible dajouter le sender
                                        }
                                    } catch (e) {
                                        // probleme dans l'ajout du sender
                                    }


                                } else {
                                    // impossible de create le message
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                // problem dans la creation du message
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        // bad token

                    }
                } else {
                    console.error(e); // something went wrong
                    //  console.log('erreur user nulll');
                }
            } else {
                //console.log('erreur impossible de recup le user');
                console.error(e); // something went wrong

            }
        });


    }


});
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least the relevant code.

Comment: Its not a problem of code for exemple it works fine in my country but for a reason i dont know the client is in usa and he can only connect and see messages but not post a message

Comment: Not much we can do with the information you've provided. Run some network diagnostics.

Comment: I know there is not a lot information to give about the problem what but since i can't make a diagnosis in the client computer i would like to know if the port i use is the problem

Comment: Again, i'd recommend you to post some code. The user is logging in and seeing posts. Sounds like a bug to me, not a problem with the port.

Comment: Ok i added the client and server code sorry for the size of the server code but just to clarify something the app work very well in my computer and other computers thats why i think it's not a bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134599/discussion-between-cviejo-and-user3741442).

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that it's not a bug, only that the conditions are not present on your machine